# Is it possible to exclude log statements from Checkstyle?

Tags: java, checkstyle

I'd like to stop log statements triggering Checkstyle's "[Multiple String Literals](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html#MultipleStringLiterals)" rule. That is, if a string is repeated in multiple log statements in a class, then Checkstyle should ignore it.

I don't want to litter my code with dozens of `//CHECKSTYLE:OFF/ON` commands around log statements and, as far as I can tell, neither of the appropriate config options (ignoreStringsRegexp and ignoreContextOccurence) can be used for this purpose.

Comment: nope! AFAIK, you can switch off the check entirely for your project if you don't want it, but can't make it work just for log statements unfortunately. I typically just get around such errors by creating string constants for repeated text.

Comment: @aishwarya Yeah, that's what I'm trying to avoid. I want to keep it on for other instances of multiple string literals, as it is useful for avoiding magic values littering the code, but extracting log text to constants seems worse. I guess it's because logging is generally a separate concern, pushing the text into the class constants seems like polluting the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, that is impossible out of the box. What you are really asking for is a modification of behavior for one check. The standard way of implementing such a thing is by implementing your own [custom check](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html). (Another way would be by implementing a [filter](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingfilters.html), but I think in your case you need a check, not a filter.)

Comment: In fact, I disabled some rules from the checkstyle configuration on several occasions because of just that kind of problem - the check just doesn't cover my kinds of exceptional situations. Writing and testing the custom check can easily take an entire day or two, so it may not be worth the while ...